# Expanded 24-simplices in the Leech polytope

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polytopes, lattice-polytopes

The vertex coordinate set for the contact polytope of the Leech lattice listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice) contains all permutations of:

- $\{4,-4,0^{22}\}$
- $\{-3,1^{23}\}$
- $\{3,-1^{23}\}$

The convex hull of these 600 vertices is an expanded 24-simplex, meaning that there is a compound of expanded 24-simplices using the vertices and long edges of the Leech lattice’s contact polytope. How many expanded simplices are in this compound?